# Extract substring after matching pattern

Tags: json, regex, grep

I am trying to extract a substring after matching a pattern in a string.

Now I can't share my hole file but let's take this example.

From this string:

```
{"code":"S02A5","name":"18\" Leichtmetallräder Doppelspeiche 397","price":"0","standard":"false"}
```

I want to extract this substring

```
18\" Leichtmetallräder Doppelspeiche 397
```

So far I tried the following :

This matches to many results

```
grep -oP '(?<="code":".....","name":")[^"]+'
```

I know that the first char after **"name":"** is always **1**, so I tried to use this in the following command, and the return is **8\** which is not that bad because I can add the **1** afterwards.

```
grep -oP '(?<="code":".....","name":"1)[^"]+'
```

The problem is that I can't find a way to retrieve the rest of the substring needed, because there's an extra quotation mark after that backslash.

Any ideas how can I solve this?

Comment: Please use a tool like `jq` for handling structured, formatted data like JSON.  Using `grep` to do it is like stirring paint with a screwdriver.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like JSON, use for example `jq`:

```
$ jq '.name' file
"18\" Leichtmetallräder Doppelspeiche 397"
```

or

```
$ jq -r '.name' file
18" Leichtmetallräder Doppelspeiche 397
```

**Update**:

If you need to use `grep`

```
$ grep -oP '(?<="name":")(\\"|[^"])+' file
18\" Leichtmetallräder Doppelspeiche 397
```

Explained:

- `(?<="name":")` positive lookbehind *preceeded by `"name":"`*
- *followed by `\"`s or non-quotes*

**OR**:

Maybe it should be:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<="name":")((?<![^\\]\\)\\"|[^"])+' file
```

since that would match `\"` and `\\\"` but not `\\"`

Comment: This look fine, but the problem is that I have just a text file (a payload)  as an input file, nothing more.

Comment: Updated with a `grep` solution.

Comment: This works just fine for this example, but for my hole file, this retrieves more substrings. But if I adjust it it should work fine. thanks

Comment: That's why it's important to make as detailed sample as possible. We can't guess what is in the real data and leave it the question poster to finalize the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering Perl, this should work

```
/tmp> export data='{"code":"S02A5","name":"18\" Leichtmetallräder Doppelspeiche 397","price":"0","standard":"false"}'
/tmp> echo $data | perl -ne  ' /\"name\":(.+?),/ and print "$1\n" '
"18\" Leichtmetallräder Doppelspeiche 397"
/tmp>
```